# How to install configure npm & round-node on linux(Centos 6.7)

Tags: github, ssh, npm

I'm getting error message whenever running

```
`npm install round-node`
```

Command on linux (centOs 6.7)

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd round-node@0.5.1 coffee -o lib -c src (wd=/home/authen                                                      ta/public_html/json/round-node)
/nter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': /
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/root/.s                                                      -h/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': |


npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b: Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b: Received disconnect from 192.30.252.129: 11: Bye Bye
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b:
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/GemHQ/jsck.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-github-com-GemHQ-jsck-git-1419679b: and the repository exists.
```

node -v  v4.2.1

npm -v  2.14.7